# Get capitalized keys in maven archetypes

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html describes how to create a simple maven archetype and that's is pretty clear, I am here to ask if there is a way (and in case how) to manipulate properties defined in the archetype-descriptor.

In particular, how to get capitalized values of some properties? (without regard how user write them)

For example

```xml
<archetype-descriptor name="example" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-archetype-plugin/archetype-descriptor/1.0.0" >
    
  <requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="name">
    </requiredProperty>
  </requiredProperties>
```

I'd like to have the value of key **name** capitalized